# How to encode / decode LISP-formatted matrices in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I am new to `python`. I am using `XML RPC` to communicate between **`lisp`** and **`python`** and I notice that the XML encoding of matrices ( which are all I am passing back and forth ) is very verbose. For example, the following `lisp` matrix:

```
((1 1)(2 2)(3 3)(4 4))
```

becomes over 20 times longer once encoded in XML:

```
<array><data><value><array><data><value><int>1</int></value><value><int>1</int></value></data>
</array></value><value><array><data><value><int>2</int></value><value><int>2</int></value></data>
</array></value><value><array><data><value><int>3</int></value><value><int>3</int></value></data>
</array></value><value><array><data><value><int>4</int></value><value><int>4</int></value></data>
</array></value></data></array>
```

So I was wondering **what would be the easiest way to create Python functions that inter-convert between strings** like `“((1 1)(2 2)(3 3)(4 4))”` **and** the corresponding Python **lists**.

Comment: Do you have to use XML?

Comment: How about JSON?  You can use something like CL-JSON (http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/) for Lisp and the standard json library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for python.

Comment: Just do it manually. Looks easy enough.

Comment: def parse(lst): return [x.split() for x in lst[2:-2].split(')(')] #dirty but works. Transformation from list to string easier